# Crash after attempting to restore realm

Tags: android, realm

I'm attempting to implement a backup/restore functionality for my android application using Realm. After I restore the data from the backup, if I try to access any information (that would request data from realm), the app crashes `A/libc: Fatal signal 7 (SIGBUS), code 2, fault addr 0x9694d000 in tid 5047 (...), pid 5047 (...)`

Keep in mind that the after reopening the app, data is restored (so backup/restore works as expected apart from the crash)

This is my `RealmBackup` class

```
public class RealmBackup {

    private final static String TAG = RealmBackup.class.getName();

    private Context context;
    private Realm realm;

    public RealmBackup(Context context) {
        this.realm = Realm.getInstance(Realm.getDefaultConfiguration());
        this.context = context;
    }

    public void backup() {

        File exportRealmFile = null;

        File exportRealmPATH = context.getExternalFilesDir(null);
        String exportRealmFileName = "default.realm";


        // create a backup file
        exportRealmFile = new File(exportRealmPATH, exportRealmFileName);

        // if backup file already exists, delete it
        exportRealmFile.delete();

        // copy current realm to backup file
        realm.writeCopyTo(exportRealmFile);

        String msg = "File exported to Path: " + context.getExternalFilesDir(null);

        realm.close();

    }

    public void restore() {

        //Restore
        File exportRealmPATH = context.getExternalFilesDir(null);
        String FileName = "default.realm";

        String restoreFilePath = context.getExternalFilesDir(null) + "/" + FileName;

        copyBundledRealmFile(restoreFilePath, FileName);

    }

    private void copyBundledRealmFile(String oldFilePath, String outFileName) {
        try {
            File file = new File(context.getFilesDir(), outFileName);

            FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);

            FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(oldFilePath));

            byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
            int bytesRead;
            while ((bytesRead = inputStream.read(buf)) > 0) {
                outputStream.write(buf, 0, bytesRead);
            }
            outputStream.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private String dbPath() {

        return realm.getPath();
    }
}
```

And whenever I'm trying to backup/restore the data I'm simply calling `realmBackup.backup()` or `restore`. The problem, I believe is that the realm must be reopened after the restore occured with the new data, however, I'm unsure how to do that, I've tried using whether

```
    Realm.init(this);
    RealmConfiguration config = new RealmConfiguration
            .Builder()
            .deleteRealmIfMigrationNeeded()
            .build();
    Realm.setDefaultConfiguration(config);
```

or simply `realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();` but that didn't quite work.

Answer (score 0):

You can't just delete and overwrite an open Realm as "restore", you must ensure that `Realm.getGlobalInstanceCount(Realm.getDefaultConfiguration()) == 0` first.

To do that, you must call `realm.close()` on the instances that are opened.

Also, if the app was updated with a new schema, your backup would be deleted by `deleteIfMigrationNeeded`, so look out for that

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately I'm not really familiar with realm yet, I've tried closing all opened instances using `if (realm != null) realm.close();` but that made the program throw `This Realm instance has already been closed, making it unusable.`, yet Global Instance Count is still 1 when I try to call the restore.

Also, what do you mean by `deleteIfMigrationNeeded` interfering with the backup? Should I delete that line?

Comment: Well think about it, if you try to open an old backed up Realm with an old schema in a new version of the app, then a migration will be needed, and you configured it to delete it if a migration is needed :D as for throwing `has already been closed`, you need to re-open the file and reset the RealmResults you're observing with the new instance. The global instance count will only be 0 if Local iinstance count reaches 0.

Comment: I think I might be missing something here, I went to every single realm instance and closed it, global count is 1 and I get the `has already been closed` error. If I comment all `.close();` lines, the program will run just fine but the global count is still 1. So the `close();` made no difference in terms of instance counts. Also, thanks for the `deleteIfMigrationNeeded` explanation. Makes sense

Comment: If it is 1, that means there is 1 other thread where Realm is still open, and not closed.

Comment: I added a toast that displays number of global instances if it's != 0

I've been playing around with `.close();`, I've searched the whole project for realm instances and whether I close none or all of them, that toast still displays `1` when I try to restore the backup. Really have no idea what I'm missing here.

Comment: As I said, if you have any background thread operations where you open Realm with `Realm.getInstance()`, then that needs to be closed as well.

Comment: I found the problem, the realm won't close before I try to restore. I do `realm.close(); if (Realm.getGlobalInstanceCount(Realm.getDefaultConfiguration()) == 0) { ...do restore things... }` and it never reaches the `if`. After the `if` statement, `realm.isClosed();` returns `false`

Any clue what to do?

Comment: I can't possibly know how many Realm instances you open on which threads at a given time; I also can't know if you close them as per recommendation in the official docs... O_O **but** you can try putting `while(!realm.isClosed()) realm.close()` which would force close the current thread's Realm. Test it thoroughly afterwards.

Answer (score -1):

**Clean** the project, **uninstall** and **reinstall** the app.